# Query Points with radius (in meters) in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial

Hi I am am having trouble getting all documents within a radius R (metres) within range of latitude and longitude coordinates X and Y respectively

I am using a 2D legacy index on my collection

```
db.users.createIndex({'location': '2d'});
```

I am trying the following:

```
var users = db.collection('users');
users.find( { location:
                 { $geoWithin
                       { $center
                            [ [ Y, X ], R / 6378100 ]
                    } } });
```

I am pretty sure it is [Y, X] longitude first then latitude last. 6378100 is the radius of the earth according to google. I have points that should be < 50m apart so R = 50 should find them however I have to make R around 4000 which is rather odd. Any ideas?

Comment: I might be wrong about it, but as far as I can see, you are dividing the search radius by earth's radius. So when `R=50` your actual search radius would be ... _very_ small. Simply remove that division (`/ 6378100`) and you should be fine.

Comment: Hey Markus, that's the thing I want to scan a really small area such as a circle with a 50m radius that's why I divide by that number. Anyway i think i found the solution. I used the $centerSphere query instead of $center and it seems to work good now ...

Answer (score 4):

- With [`$center`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/center/), the circle radius is expressed in the same units as your coordinates; it is most useful for *flat* geometry.
- With [`$centerSphere`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/), the circle radius is expressed in *radians*; it is specifically useful for *spherical* geometry.

As explained in the MongoDB doc [*"Calculate Distance Using Spherical Geometry"*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/#calculate-distance-using-spherical-geometry), your conversion function `R / 6378100` will convert your radius in radians, and is tailored to use with `$centerSphere` -- not `$center`.

---

Please note that is you want to stick with `$center`, you have to convert meters to [decimal degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees), and that relation is not linear. From [an answer by @whuber on GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters), at the equator a routh estimate is *"111,111 meters (111.111 km) in the y direction is 1 degree (of latitude) and 111,111 * cos(latitude) meters in the x direction is 1 degree (of longitude)"*.